# Token HMAC vs jwt refresh token

Tags: jwt, hmac

I'm following [this tutorial for securing API](https://youtu.be/NtAnyDJhkkg?t=459) (at 7:41)

The author suggested to:

Include a timestamp in the signed payload to protect against replays

1. JWT will help you with this
2. If you use HMAC, you will have to come up with your own convention.

Any example code on how to do token refresh with HMAC please?

I'm hitting an error where while I'm calling an API using HMAC, the token expired (expire every 2 minutes) and it throws an error back before I can request for a new token.

JWT has a refresh token will solve this issue (by having longer refresh interval e.g. 30 days). But will it actually solve the problem I'm having by switching from HMAC to JWT?